# How can I access a bower package as an ES6 module?

Tags: ember.js, bower, ecmascript-6, ember-app-kit

I'm trying to migrate an ember app to use the [ember app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit). The code requires the accounting.js library. In the pre-app-kit version the file was loaded via a script tag in `index.html`

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/accounting.js/0.3.2/accounting.min.js"></script>
```

and accessed in the views through the global namespace

```
App.MoneyField= Em.TextField.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var value = accounting.formatMoney(this.get("money") / 100, '');
    this.set('value', value);
  };
  // other functions omitted
});
```

In the app-kit version, I've included `accounting.js` as a bower dependency. In `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ember-app-kit",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.1.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "qunit": "~1.12.0",
    "ember": "~1.4.0-beta.2",
    "ember-data": "~1.0.0-beta.6",
    "ember-resolver": "git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jj-abrams-resolver.git#master",
    "ic-ajax": "~0.3.0",
    "ember-testing-httpRespond": "~0.1.1",
    "accounting":"~0.3.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ember": "~1.4.0-beta.2"
  }
 }
```

When I try to build the app, it gives the error

```
W117: 'accounting' is not defined.
```

I understand why this is and know I need some sort of `import accounting from ...` statement.

How do I import a package installed via bower as an ES6 module?

Comment: I would guess `import accounting from '/vendor/accounting/accounting';`. However I tried it and got the following error: `Uncaught Error: Could not find module /vendor/accounting/accounting Source:  'http://localhost:8000/vendor/loader.js:21'`. With requirejs I would add a shim to the config file, sadly I don't know how to do it with EAK.

Comment: Apparently there is something coming in the near future: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/12/17/whats-coming-in-ember-in-2014.html The `ember-cli` is able to make a shim.

Comment: I created an issue for this feature: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/511

Comment: Thanks @WillemdeWit. It sounds like what I was trying to do isn't possible at the moment, but hopefully will be soon.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this was asked a few months ago, but since then, Ember App Kit has been succeeded by [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli), and this provides a very straight forward means to access either bower or npm dependencies.

- [Non-AMD asset](http://www.ember-cli.com/#standard-non-amd-asset)
- [AMD asset](http://www.ember-cli.com/#standard-amd-asset)

With regards to being accessed as ES6 modules:

- Non-AMD assets cannot be accessed as an ES6 module, you simply access them through the global variable that they export.

  - e.g. `moment`
- AMD assets, on the other hand, can be accessed through the ES6 `import` syntax

  - e.g. `import { raw as icAjaxRaw } from 'ic-ajax';`

---

Worth also mentioning, that ember-cli supports an add-on system now, which can make importing these things as simple as adding them to the `package.json` of your project. Some of the more popular libraries already have ember-cli addons for them. [This post](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/building-ember-addons) describes how you can write your own.

Comment: Both links do no longer exist.